# How can I programmatically open a user specified calling/sms/mms Android app?

Tags: java, android

I've created an address book app, and am trying to add some features to it.  What I'm trying to do right now is add the ability to longclick a phone number, and then either call/text/mms the number.  This all works fine with phones, but I was wondering how to do this on tablets, since they will not have that same ability.  The device I'm debugging on is a tablet, and I use HeyWire for texting.  I know there are apps out there for calling via WiFi as well.  Here's what I have so far for the texting section of my switch statement:

```
case 1:                                                     //SMS
  if(CanCallAndText)
    {
    CustomSMSDialog SendSMSDialog = new CustomSMSDialog(BrowseListActivity.this, ParsedPhoneNum);
    SendSMSDialog.setTitle("Sending text to " + PhoneNum);
    SendSMSDialog.setCancelable(false);
    SendSMSDialog.show();
    }
  else
    {
    try
      {
      Intent WiFiSMS = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      WiFiSMS.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + PhoneNum));
      WiFiSMS.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(WiFiSMS, ""), 0);
      }//endtry
    catch(Exception e)
      {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }//endcatch
    }//endelse
  break;
```

I don't know if I'm doing the create chooser incorrectly or not, but it simply tells me that no apps can handle it.  Thank you!

EDIT: Ooh, spotted a slight error that I should fix tomorrow.  The URI should include ParsedPhoneNum, instead of PhoneNum.  Anything other than a number, like a -, would be included in PhoneNum.

Comment: What result did you get for this?

Comment: It just tells me "No application can perform this action."

Comment: Okay, I finally got a few minutes today to play around with this, and I discovered that I shouldn't set the type of the intent for non-calling devices.  Now it brings up a list with HeyWire included.  However, for calling, it tries to add the number to my contacts, instead of bringing up a list of VoIP apps (I have two installed).  I'm not at my dev computer right now, or I'd post some code.

EDIT: If I remember correctly:

`Intent WiFiCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
WiFiCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+" + ParsedPhoneNum));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(WiFiCall, ""), 0);`